# Is "who" omitted here?

Tags: sentence-structure

> From a teacher who never reveals his thoughts to **one
>   goes** China to look for a hot girl, however turns out he gets a
>   typical Taiwanese girlfriend.

Regarding the bold part, Is "who" omitted? Does it mean "one who goes"? I think the  sentence structure is "From A to B", and can I interpret it as "From a teacher who (...) to a person who goes China (...)"?

Comment: There's far more wrong with the sentence than just the part in bold. Fixing just that won't fix the rest of it.

Comment: The full context can cause a lot of things to make sense that wouldn't otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right, that "who" was omitted. But doesn't really seem like a question of grammar and usage, but one of trying to figure out what someone meant by a statement that has errors in it.

That isn't the way a normal idiomatic sentence or text should read.

My opinion is that the writer meant to say something like this:

> From a teacher who never reveals his thoughts to one [who] goes China
>   to look for a hot girl, however [it] turns out he gets a typical
>   Taiwanese girlfriend.

Comment: Your corrected sentence is still nonsensical. What comes after the comma doesn't make any sense in relation to what comes before it. (I don't mean the grammar, but what's actually said.)

Comment: @JasonBassford , Yes you are right, but this sounds like it is meant for a specific reader who I figure probably  gets the point of whatever the guy meant to say.